# Issue with incorrect usage of cluster name in GridDB

Tags: griddb

When running GridDB manually using `gs_startnode` and  `gs_joincluster`, I keep having issues with incorrect usage of cluster name. I fixed both `gs_cluster.json` in `/var/lib/gridstore/conf` and `/usr/griddb/ conf/` but the issue persisted until it was found that the default cluster name when running `gs_joincluster` is not set to the common clustername (myCluster) but defaultCluster.

```
parser.add_option("-c", "--clusterName", dest="clusterName", 
                   default="defaultCluster", 
                   help="cluster name (default is defaultCluster)") 
 parser.add_option("-n", "--nodeNum", dest="minNodeNum", 
                   type="int", default=1, 
                   help="the number of nodes constituting a cluster (default is 1)") 
 parser.add_option("-w", "--wait", action='callback', callback=\ 
                     util.optional_arg(0), dest="wait_time",default=None, 
                   help="wait for completion of joining to a cluster") 
 (options, args) = parser.parse_args()
```